# How to store viewed movie ID in cookie. Single cookie vs multiple cookies

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I need to save in cookie information about watched movies/streams on my site. In short, my site is embedding youtube/vimeo(..) movies, each page has unique id ex:
`/video/play/1/` loads movie with id '123sadzXC' from YouTube.

I want to count unique views depending on cookie (I know that user can delete cookie, use private mode and so on..).

So I want to create a cookie which will contain information about watched video id.

And here is my question: which approach is better?

1. Store cookie for each movie/stream with different `path` variable
2. Storing all watched movies in single cookie with serialized array + some encryption for safety?

Comment: I think 2nd approach will work because in 1st approach you will have a limit of 30 cookies per website.

Comment: @FarooqKhan so, no matter if I set a `path` or not, maximum number of cookies is 30 (depending on browser), right?

Comment: I guess yes, you can check [here](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/). So, storing list of watched movies in an encrypted format with a single cookie text limit is about 4093 bytes. I think it will serve the purpose.

Comment: @FarooqKhan thank you. Please submit an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: glad it helped.cheers :-)